# Redirect connection to IP address X to IP address Y

Tags: iptables

I have an application that tries to connect to 10.0.0.172. I would like these connections to be redirected to localhost. What is the best way to achieve this?

(I've just learned that /etc/hosts only works for DNS requests, and not for IP addresses.)

I think I need to write some iptables commands but I've never used those before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -s source_ip -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

The above example redirect all http requests to localhost on same port 80. Of course, you can change the ports and protocol according to your needs. However, there is one more requirement that this host should be receiving this traffic to be able to redirect it (such as your gateway).

If you don't need to filter any traffic, you can just set default policy to `ACCEPT` for `INPUT`.

Comment: I'm not only interested in port 80, I want *all* traffic to 10.0.0.172 be redirected to localhost.

Comment: @aioobe: So, you can remove the part `-p tcp --dport 80` and also `--to-ports 80` from the above rule.

Comment: ...also, I don't know what I should write for `source_ip`. The local IP which I want to redirect connections *to* or `10.0.0.172`?

Comment: If you don't know the source IP, you can use the option `-d destination_ip` to apply the rule only to specific destination addresses.

Comment: It could that masquerade is also needed `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p all -j MASQUERADE`